# Comparing values from two SQL SELECTs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following two `SELECT` statements, I'd like to compare the outputs from these two to get the `IDs` of the amounts don't match.

The `GROUP BY` and `SUM`s in the first statement seem to be complicating things:

```
SELECT CreditAHID,
SUM(Debit) as CCDebit,
SUM(Credit) as CCCredit,
FROM FS_2015_June.dbo.CCs
GROUP BY CreditAHID

SELECT ID as CreditAHID,
JuneDebit as AHDebit,
JuneCredit as AHCredit,
FROM FS_2015_2016.dbo.AHs
```

Is there any way to combine them to something like this?

```
SELECT ID ... WHERE (CCDebit != AHDebit) OR (CCCredit != AHCredit)
```

Comment: Do you have any keys between those table ?

Comment: Do you mind attempting to explain more clearly what you're hoping to achieve? Perhaps offer some sample ins and outs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query below:

```
SELECT
    ResultSet1.*
    , ResultSet2.*
FROM (
    SELECT CreditAHID
        ,SUM(Debit) AS CCDebit
        ,SUM(Credit) AS CCCredit
    FROM FS_2015_June.dbo.CCs
    GROUP BY CreditAHID
    ) ResultSet1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID AS CreditAHID
        ,JuneDebit AS AHDebit
        ,JuneCredit AS AHCredit
    FROM FS_2015_2016.dbo.AHs
    ) ResultSet2 ON ResultSet1.CreditAHID = ResultSet2.CreditAHID
WHERE ResultSet1.CCDebit <> ResultSet2.AHDebit
    AND ResultSet1.CCCredit <> ResultSet2.AHCredit
```

This query will return the combination of both results where a CreditAHID matches in both results and where the `CCDebit` and `CCCredit` is not equal to `AHDebit` and `AHCredit` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with CTE:

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT CreditAHID,
SUM(Debit) as CCDebit,
SUM(Credit) as CCCredit,
FROM FS_2015_June.dbo.CCs
GROUP BY CreditAHID
), cte2 as (
SELECT ID as CreditAHID,
JuneDebit as AHDebit,
JuneCredit as AHCredit,
FROM FS_2015_2016.dbo.AHs)

SELECT * FROM cte
UNION
SELECT * FROM cte2
WHERE CCDebit <> AHDebit and CCCredit <> AHCredit
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work...
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write as:

```
select T1.CreditAHID as [CCs], T2.CreditAHID as [AHs]
from (
SELECT CreditAHID,
SUM(Debit) as CCDebit,
SUM(Credit) as CCCredit,
FROM FS_2015_June.dbo.CCs
GROUP BY CreditAHID) T1
full Join (
SELECT ID as CreditAHID,
JuneDebit as AHDebit,
JuneCredit as AHCredit,
FROM FS_2015_2016.dbo.AHs) T2 
on T1.CreditAHID = T2.CreditAHID
where T1.CCDebit <> AHDebit 
and T1.CCCredit <> T2.AHCredit
```

Comment: Clean, and exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks to you & Radu :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXCEPT` like this:

```
SELECT CreditAHID,
SUM(Debit) as CCDebit,
SUM(Credit) as CCCredit,
FROM FS_2015_June.dbo.CCs
GROUP BY CreditAHID
EXCEPT
SELECT ID as CreditAHID,
JuneDebit as AHDebit,
JuneCredit as AHCredit,
FROM FS_2015_2016.dbo.AHs
```

Note, that [EXCEPT](https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tsql%20except) returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query. So, if the second query contains more rows, it should be referred first.

Comment: Not really scalable, since you'd have to check which query returns more rows to switch their order. Once adding more data, you'd have to manually check for consistency. It's an interesting solution, but I wouldn't apply it in a real business environment.

Comment: It can be easily done using two `EXCEPT` statements with `UNION ALL` statement, if you doubt about the data. It can be for sure used in real business environment - of course depending on the given situation.

Comment: Yes, but it's not scallable. Also, you didn't mention adding any `UNION ALL` in your solution. That may make me change my mind regarding your solution, but I still think of it a bit like scratching your left ear with your right hand.

Comment: As I said, it always depends on your data, so this is just a clearer variant of solving this or similar issues :-)

Comment: I didn't even know about SQL EXCEPT usage... thanks for an application of it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using good old **not exists** and **having** like this:

```
SELECT CreditAHID, SUM(Debit) as CCDebit, SUM(Credit) as CCCredit
   FROM FS_2015_June.dbo.CCs c
GROUP BY CreditAHID
having not exists 
       (SELECT 1
          FROM FS_2015_2016.dbo.AHs
         where ID = c.CreditAHID and 
        (Sum(c.Debit) = JuneDebit or Sum(c.Credit) = JuneCredit))
```

Here is an example I made in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d02b8/1/0